PIXI.js 8 create texture directly from base64 image data
In the PIXI playground, I tried to create texture directly from base64 image data but it's not working:
import { Application, Assets, Sprite, Texture } from 'pixi.js';

(async () =>
{
    // Create a new application
    const app = new Application();

    // Initialize the application
    await app.init({ background: '#1099bb', resizeTo: window });

    // Append the application canvas to the document body
    document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);

    // Load the bunny texture
    // const texture = await Assets.load('https://pixijs.com/assets/bunny.png');

    // Base64 encoded bunny image
    const bunnyBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,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"
    
    // Create a bunny Sprite
    const texture = Texture.from(bunnyBase64);
    const bunny = new Sprite(texture);

    // Center the sprite's anchor point
    bunny.anchor.set(0.5);

    // Move the sprite to the center of the screen
    bunny.x = app.screen.width / 2;
    bunny.y = app.screen.height / 2;

    app.stage.addChild(bunny);

    // Listen for animate update
    app.ticker.add((time) =>
    {
        // Just for fun, let's rotate mr rabbit a little.
        // * Delta is 1 if running at 100% performance *
        // * Creates frame-independent transformation *
        bunny.rotation += 0.1 * time.deltaTime;
    });
})();


In my web application, the data is already in base64, so there is no loading process from the image url.
I have tried to use base64 image directly to create texture (const texture = Texture.from(bunnyBase64), but the image is not shown. The expected result would display image using loader (const texture = await Assets.load('https://pixijs.com/assets/bunny.png')). This question is similar, but it uses PIXI 7 I think.

The snippet below is what was missing in your piece of code;
const bunnyImage = new Image();
bunnyImage.src = bunnyBase64;

// Create a bunny Sprite
const texture = Texture.from(bunnyImage);
const bunny = new Sprite(texture);

The code above, converts the base64 image into an image which can be used in PIXI.js to create a Texture which would then be used to create the sprite.
Find updated code below:
import { Application, Assets, Sprite, Texture } from 'pixi.js';

(async () =>
{
// Create a new application
const app = new Application();

// Initialize the application
await app.init({ background: '#1099bb', resizeTo: window });

// Append the application canvas to the document body
document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);

// Load the bunny texture
// const texture = await Assets.load('https://pixijs.com/assets/bunny.png');

// Base64 encoded bunny image
const bunnyBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAlCAYAAABcZvm2AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAWNJREFUeNrsV8sNwjAMbUqBBWACxB2pQ8AKcGALTsAJuDEFB1gBhuDAuWICmICPQh01pXWdJqEFcaglRGRbfonjPLuMc+5QwhjLGEJfZusjxZOL9akZKye9G98vPMfvsAx4qBfKwfzBL9s6uUHpI6U/u7+BKGkNb/H6umtk7MczF0HyfKS4zo/k/4AgTV8DOizrqX8oECgC+MGa8lGJp9sJDiAB8nyqYoglvJOPbP97IqoATGxWVZeXJlMQwYHA3piF8wJIblOVNBBxe3TPMLoHIKtxrbS7AAbBrA4Y5NaPAXf8LjN6wKZ0RaZOnlAFZnuXInVR4FTE6eYp0olPhhshtXsAwY3PquoAJNkIY33U7HTs7hYBwV24ItUKqDwgKF3VzAZ6k8HF+B1BMF8xRJbeJoqMXHZAAQ1kwoluURCdzepEugGEImBrIADB7I4lyfbJLlw92FKE6b5hVd+ktv4vAQYASMWxvlAAvcsAAAAASUVORK5CYII="




 const bunnyImage = new Image();
    bunnyImage.src = bunnyBase64;

    // Create a bunny Sprite
    const texture = Texture.from(bunnyImage);
    const bunny = new Sprite(texture);

    // Center the sprite's anchor point
    bunny.anchor.set(0.5);

    // Move the sprite to the center of the screen
    bunny.x = app.screen.width / 2;
    bunny.y = app.screen.height / 2;

    app.stage.addChild(bunny);

    // Listen for animate update
    app.ticker.add((time) =>
    {
        // Just for fun, let's rotate mr rabbit a little.
        // * Delta is 1 if running at 100% performance *
        // * Creates frame-independent transformation *
        bunny.rotation += 0.1 * time.deltaTime;
    });
})();

